# Azure Function in Python with Timer Trigger and RunOnStartup fails locally with error "Did not find any initialized language workers"

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function in Python with a Timer Trigger. To test locally on demand, I have the option RunOnStartup set to True ([Microsoft documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=python#configuration)).

My simplified Python code looks like this:

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import sendgrid
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
import azure.storage.blob
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
import wikipedia
import json, os
from datetime import datetime

//Initializations

def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest, inputblob: func.InputStream) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()

    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)

    // Do stuff
```

My function.json (with the timer trigger and a blob input binding):

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "mytimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 30 9 * * *",
      "runOnStartup": true
    },
    {
      "name": "inputblob",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "sharefiles/versionIds.json",
      "connection": "shareFilesConnString",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ]
}
```

And my hosts.json:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
      "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
      "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  }
}
```

However, I get the following output when running the function locally on my computer to test. The most noticeable error is:

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function:
>   Functions.. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Did not find
>   any initialized language workers.

```
Executing task: .venv\Scripts\activate ; func host start <

Found Python version 3.7.5 (python).

                  %%%%%%
                 %%%%%%
            @   %%%%%%    @
          @@   %%%%%%      @@
       @@@    %%%%%%%%%%%    @@@
     @@      %%%%%%%%%%        @@
       @@         %%%%       @@
         @@      %%%       @@
           @@    %%      @@
                %%
                %

Azure Functions Core Tools (2.7.1948 Commit hash: 29a0626ded3ae99c4111f66763f27bb9fb564103)    
Function Runtime Version: 2.0.12888.0
[12/10/2019 8:11:29 PM] File 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' is not found, 'dotnet' invocation will rely on the PATH environment variable.
[12/10/2019 8:11:29 PM] Building host: startup suppressed: 'False', configuration suppressed: 'False', startup operation id: 'ca4aefed-0190-45d6-9ad6-d22c0cd6abf1'
[12/10/2019 8:11:29 PM] Reading host configuration file 'C:\Users\<redacted>\Desktop\TimerTrigger\host.json'
[12/10/2019 8:11:29 PM] Host configuration file read:
[12/10/2019 8:11:29 PM] {
[12/10/2019 8:11:29 PM]   "version": "2.0",
[12/10/2019 8:11:29 PM]   "extensionBundle": {
[12/10/2019 8:11:29 PM]     "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
[12/10/2019 8:11:29 PM]     "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
[12/10/2019 8:11:29 PM]   }
[12/10/2019 8:11:29 PM] }
[12/10/2019 8:11:29 PM] Looking for extension bundle Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle 
at C:\Users\<redacted>\AppData\Local\Temp\Functions\ExtensionBundles\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle
[12/10/2019 8:11:29 PM] Found a matching extension bundle at C:\Users\<redacted>\AppData\Local\Temp\Functions\ExtensionBundles\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle\1.1.1
[12/10/2019 8:11:29 PM] Fetching information on versions of extension bundle Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle available on https://functionscdn.azureedge.net/public/ExtensionBundles/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle/index.json
[12/10/2019 8:11:29 PM] Skipping bundle download since it already exists at path C:\Users\<redacted>\AppData\Local\Temp\Functions\ExtensionBundles\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle\1.1.1
[12/10/2019 8:11:29 PM] Loading Extention bundle from C:\Users\<redacted>\AppData\Local\Temp\Functions\ExtensionBundles\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle\1.1.1
[12/10/2019 8:11:29 PM] Reading functions metadata
[12/10/2019 8:11:29 PM] 1 functions found
[12/10/2019 8:11:29 PM] Loading startup extension 'AzureStorage'
[12/10/2019 8:11:29 PM] Loaded extension 'AzureStorage' (3.0.10.0)
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM] File 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' is not found, 'dotnet' invocation will rely on the PATH environment variable.
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM] Initializing Warmup Extension.
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM] Initializing Host. OperationId: 'ca4aefed-0190-45d6-9ad6-d22c0cd6abf1'.[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM] Host initialization: ConsecutiveErrors=0, StartupCount=1, OperationId=ca4aefed-0190-45d6-9ad6-d22c0cd6abf1
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM] LoggerFilterOptions
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM] {
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]   "MinLevel": "None",
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]   "Rules": [
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]     {
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]       "ProviderName": null,
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]       "CategoryName": null,
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]       "LogLevel": null,
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]       "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0"
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]     },
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]     {
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]       "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.SystemLoggerProvider",
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]       "CategoryName": null,
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]       "LogLevel": "None",
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]       "Filter": null
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]     },
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]     {
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]       "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.SystemLoggerProvider",
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]       "CategoryName": null,
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]       "LogLevel": null,
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]       "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0"
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]     }
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]   ]
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM] }
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM] FunctionResultAggregatorOptions
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM] {
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]   "BatchSize": 1000,
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]   "FlushTimeout": "00:00:30",
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]   "IsEnabled": true
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM] }
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM] SingletonOptions
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM] {
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]   "LockPeriod": "00:00:15",
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]   "ListenerLockPeriod": "00:00:15",
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]   "LockAcquisitionTimeout": "10675199.02:48:05.4775807",
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]   "LockAcquisitionPollingInterval": "00:00:05",
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]   "ListenerLockRecoveryPollingInterval": "00:01:00"
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM] }
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM] QueuesOptions
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM] {
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]   "BatchSize": 16,
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]   "NewBatchThreshold": 8,
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]   "MaxPollingInterval": "00:00:02",
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]   "MaxDequeueCount": 5,
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]   "VisibilityTimeout": "00:00:00"
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM] }
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM] BlobsOptions
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM] {
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]   "CentralizedPoisonQueue": false
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM] }
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM] HttpOptions
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM] {
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]   "DynamicThrottlesEnabled": false,
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]   "MaxConcurrentRequests": -1,
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]   "MaxOutstandingRequests": -1,
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM]   "RoutePrefix": "api"
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM] }
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM] Starting JobHost
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM] Starting Host (HostId=desktopl8i1u40-13243865, InstanceId=49bcc245-e949-45fd-b731-1e5ccd7ebbdc, Version=2.0.12888.0, ProcessId=10432, AppDomainId=1, InDebugMode=False, InDiagnosticMode=False, FunctionsExtensionVersion=~2)
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM] Loading functions metadata
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM] 1 functions loaded
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM] Loading proxies metadata
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM] Initializing Azure Function proxies
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM] 0 proxies loaded
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM] Starting worker process:python  c:/Users/<redacted>/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.11.50794/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py --default --host 127.0.0.1 --port 9091 --wait "C:\Users\<redacted>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\python\3.7/WINDOWS/X64/worker.py" --host 127.0.0.1 --port 55800 --workerId 0edae10c-af7f-4e37-8d13-382365306813 --requestId d0d3851a-1ee8-411d-bb74-426ab04b44b6 --grpcMaxMessageLength 134217728
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM] python process with Id=13188 started
[12/10/2019 8:11:30 PM] Generating 1 job function(s)
[12/10/2019 8:11:31 PM] Found the following functions:
[12/10/2019 8:11:31 PM] Host.Functions.<functionname>
[12/10/2019 8:11:31 PM]
[12/10/2019 8:11:31 PM] Initializing function HTTP routes
[12/10/2019 8:11:31 PM] No HTTP routes mapped
[12/10/2019 8:11:31 PM]
[12/10/2019 8:11:31 PM] Host initialized (546ms)
[12/10/2019 8:11:31 PM] Executing 'Functions.<functionname>' (Reason='Timer fired at 2019-12-10T15:11:31.5531175-05:00', Id=6176e5d6-c860-4bf7-80e5-712b8919310d)
[12/10/2019 8:11:31 PM] Trigger Details: UnscheduledInvocationReason: RunOnStartup
[12/10/2019 8:12:30 PM] Starting worker process failed
[12/10/2019 8:12:30 PM] The operation has timed out.
[12/10/2019 8:12:31 PM] Starting worker process:python  c:/Users/<redacted>/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.11.50794/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py --default --host 127.0.0.1 --port 9091 --wait "C:\Users\<redacted>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\python\3.7/WINDOWS/X64/worker.py" --host 127.0.0.1 --port 55800 --workerId d68b30e0-3146-43f7-92bf-5a8f57ebf3a1 --requestId a4e0053f-b28d-44e1-9671-ac1431349d8e --grpcMaxMessageLength 134217728
[12/10/2019 8:12:31 PM] python process with Id=1524 started
[12/10/2019 8:12:31 PM] Executed 'Functions.<functionname>' (Failed, Id=6176e5d6-c860-4bf7-80e5-712b8919310d)
[12/10/2019 8:12:31 PM] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.<functionname>. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Did not find any initialized language workers.
[12/10/2019 8:12:31 PM] The next 5 occurrences of the '<functionname>' schedule (Cron: '0 30 9 * * *') will be:
[12/10/2019 8:12:31 PM] 12/11/2019 09:30:00-05:00 (12/11/2019 14:30:00Z)
[12/10/2019 8:12:31 PM] 12/12/2019 09:30:00-05:00 (12/12/2019 14:30:00Z)
[12/10/2019 8:12:31 PM] 12/13/2019 09:30:00-05:00 (12/13/2019 14:30:00Z)
[12/10/2019 8:12:31 PM] 12/14/2019 09:30:00-05:00 (12/14/2019 14:30:00Z)
[12/10/2019 8:12:31 PM] 12/15/2019 09:30:00-05:00 (12/15/2019 14:30:00Z)
[12/10/2019 8:12:31 PM]
[12/10/2019 8:12:31 PM] Host started (61122ms)
[12/10/2019 8:12:31 PM] Job host started
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\Users\<redacted>\Desktop\TimerTrigger
Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:7071
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
[12/10/2019 8:12:36 PM] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '00000000000000000000000086626BD5'.
[12/10/2019 8:12:37 PM]  INFO: Starting Azure Functions Python Worker.
[12/10/2019 8:12:37 PM]  INFO: Worker ID: d68b30e0-3146-43f7-92bf-5a8f57ebf3a1, Request ID: a4e0053f-b28d-44e1-9671-ac1431349d8e, Host Address: 127.0.0.1:55800        
[12/10/2019 8:12:37 PM]  INFO: Successfully opened gRPC channel to 127.0.0.1:55800
[12/10/2019 8:12:37 PM]  INFO: Received WorkerInitRequest, request ID a4e0053f-b28d-44e1-9671-ac1431349d8e
[12/10/2019 8:12:37 PM]  INFO: Received FunctionLoadRequest, request ID: a4e0053f-b28d-44e1-9671-ac1431349d8e, function ID: 1cf61de1-d4a3-4011-8695-98d4a973f1a9       
[12/10/2019 8:12:37 PM]  INFO: Successfully processed FunctionLoadRequest, request ID: a4e0053f-b28d-44e1-9671-ac1431349d8e, function ID: 1cf61de1-d4a3-4011-8695-98d4a973f1a9
```

What am I missing?

Comment: This looks like a race condition with the Azure Functions Runtime. It's trying to execute the function before the "Python worker" (another component of the runtime) is ready for requests causing the Runtime to not find any available worker.
Would you mind open a bug here for us to investigate further? -- https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host

Comment: Done: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5367

Comment: @AnkitKumar I see that the bug has been closed, but I'm still experiencing the same issue. azure-functions v1.0.7

Comment: The bug was closed as a duplicate of -- https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5233,
The PR for fix is -- https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/pull/5458

However, once bug is closed and Pr is merged, it takes a couple of weeks for the Functions Runtime to be deployed everywhere. You can follow the above links for updates.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

[image]

Have reproduce your error.

First, please have a check of whether there is a `dotnet.exe` under the `C:\Program Files\dotnet`

Second, please have a check of your environment variable.

Third, change the settings.json.

```
{
    "azureFunctions.deploySubpath": ".",
    "azureFunctions.scmDoBuildDuringDeployment": true,
    "azureFunctions.pythonVenv": ".venv",
    "azureFunctions.projectLanguage": "Python",
    "azureFunctions.projectRuntime": "~2",
    "debug.internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
    "python.pythonPath": ".venv\\Scripts\\python.exe"
}
```

[image]

The above picture is my settings.json. If I read correctly, I used the same settings as you.

Please change the settings.json like this:

```
{
    "azureFunctions.deploySubpath": ".",
    "azureFunctions.scmDoBuildDuringDeployment": true,
    "azureFunctions.pythonVenv": ".venv",
    "azureFunctions.projectLanguage": "Python",
    "azureFunctions.projectRuntime": "~2",
    "debug.internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
    "python.pythonPath": "/path/to/your/venv/bin/python"
}
```

[image]

The final function can be successfully run and triggered.

**Original Answer:**

Try to find the `settings.json` file,

then you can find your file like this:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "xxxxxxxxx",
    ...
}
```

change to

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/path/to/your/venv/bin/python",
    ...
}
```

I faced this error before, but with this settings function work fine.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this is the issue. My Python path was already set up to the correct location ([screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/Bdq2FU6.png))

Comment: Thank you so much for your continued help BowmanZhu. Unfortunately I'm still getting the same error.
1. I installed .NET Core 3 so that there is a dotnet.exe under the C:\Program Files\dotnet.
2. My PATH environment seems ok ([screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/MPRw47b.png))
3. My Python path seems correct. I'm not sure exactly what you're suggesting I change it to ([my venv](https://i.imgur.com/Y4E5lQF.png)) ([my Python.exe](https://i.imgur.com/DERUace.png)).

Comment: @CharlieBrown Have you modified the "python.pythonPath" of `settings.json` to "/path/to/your/venv/bin/python" as I said? Only paste this is ok, no need to modify any word.

Comment: I now modified python.pythonPath exactly as you posted, but that didn't work. The error is the same, in addition to the warning that "No Python interpreter is selected." ([screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/Y2SXVhy.png))

Comment: @CharlieBrown I also warning 'No Python interpreter is selected'. But It can work. It is strange...