# Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Architecture Arm64 is not supported for language python (issue on Mac M1 Chip)

Tags: python, azure, sqlalchemy, azure-functions

My laptop is MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2021) Apple M1 Max.

I want to run Azure function with Python.

Currently, Azure function Core tools does not support Python function development on ARM64 devices. To develop Python functions on a Mac with an M1 chip, you must run in an emulated x86 environment. To learn more, **[see x86 emulation on ARM64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#x86-emulation-on-arm64)**.

I already followed the instruction.

[Install the Azure Functions Core Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4%2Cmacos%2Ccsharp%2Cportal%2Cbash#install-the-azure-functions-core-tools)

So far, I did:

1. install Homebrew
2. Open terminal using Rosetta.
3. Also [Enable emulation in Visual Studio Code](https://Enable%20emulation%20in%20Visual%20Studio%20Code)
4. setting.json

```
    "azureFunctions.deploySubpath": ".",
    "azureFunctions.scmDoBuildDuringDeployment": true,
    "azureFunctions.pythonVenv": ".venv",
    "azureFunctions.projectLanguage": "Python",
    "azureFunctions.projectRuntime": "~4",
    "debug.internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {
       "rosetta": {
         "path": "arch",
         "args": ["-x86_64", "zsh", "-l"],
         "overrideName": true
       }
     }
}
```

5. I have .zshrc file in the root folder which my project located.

```
# rosetta terminal setup
if [ $(arch) = "i386" ]; then
    alias python="/usr/local/bin/python3"
    alias brew86='/usr/local/bin/brew'
    alias pyenv86="arch -x86_64 pyenv"
    alias func="/usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.5095/func"
fi
```

so in VS code editor, I have rosetta terminal. run arch will show i386 which emulate ARM64.

6. copy `azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.5095` folder from `opt/homebrew/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4`  past to `/usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.5095/func"` because if I install azure-functions-core-tools@4 from terminal, it always goes to  homebrew folder.

If run `func host start` in Rosetta terminal, it showed error that

Failed to initialize worker provider for: /usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.5095/workers/python

Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Architecture Arm64 is not supported for language python.
Failed to initialize worker provider for: /usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.5095/workers/python......(skip)

I already follow any solution from online, most are this way to run azure function on M1 Chip.

Is there any wrong I did or something I missing?

4/13 update
host.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I looked far and wide for  solution to this (Azure functions don't support Python on Apple Silicon) and found this comment gives a good workaround without relying on emulation: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/915#issuecomment-1342319719

You'll have to modify the paths to your homebrew azure function folder (mine is currently on 4.0.5198 where-as the instructions are for 4.0.4915).

You'll also need to repeat these steps when ever the homebrew recipe updates for Azure Functions.

Answer (score 0):

> Failed to initialize worker provider for: /usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.5095/workers/python

All the tools you have installed are correct and once again check the Azure Functions core tools, Python version is installed properly.

Check the `host.json` file to check the Python executable path is given properly with the setting of `languageWorkers:python:pythonPath`

I know that Microsoft explicitly mentioned that Functions (Python) not supported on ARM64 devices but emulated x86 environment is the provided alternative.

Give the both architectures code in the zsh environment so that it detects automatically and runs in that environment as shown in this GitHub [Article](https://gist.github.com/ahgraber/79a802544e79c2f80ae0dd2744b58cc5#homebrew).

> archcheck () {
> if [ "$(uname -p)" = "i386" ]; then
> echo "Running in i386 mode (Rosetta)"
> eval "$(/usr/local/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
> alias brew='/usr/local/homebrew/bin/brew'  # not sure aliases will set from within a function
> elif
> echo "Running in ARM mode (M1)"
> eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
> alias brew='/opt/homebrew/bin/brew'  # not sure aliases will set from within a function
> else
> echo "Unknown architecture detected: $(uname -p) // $(arch)"
> fi
> }
> alias native="arch -arm64 zsh && archcheck"
> alias rosetta="arch -x86_64 zsh && archcheck"

If still not yet resolved, you can raise the issue in the official forum of Azure Functions Host in [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues) by providing your environment and the issue details.

Comment: Hi Hari, 
I alraedy share my host.json in the post. Could you tell me more a little bit 
Python executable path is given properly with the setting of languageWorkers:python:pythonPath
not sure how to do it 
THank you so much

Comment: Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59297128/16630138) for setting up that property.

Comment: Azure functions don't work on the Arm64 processors yet due to the Python compatibility issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try add this new setting on your *.vscode/settings.json*

```
"azureFunctions.funcCliPath": "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.5095/func"
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for suggestion, but it still showed 
Failed to initialize worker provider for: /usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.5095/workers/python.

Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Architecture Arm64 is not supported for language python.

Comment: I found that I don't have path: /workers/python.
Even I add "azureFunctions.funcCliPath": "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.5095/func"
it didn't change. is there any thing I can change manually