# Issue in running Azure Functions locally in Mac M2 Machine

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I'm currently working on a project that involves Azure Functions, and I'm facing some challenges running them locally on my Mac M2 machine. I've tried following the official documentation, but I seem to encounter compatibility issues or other hurdles specific to the M2 architecture.

Azure Docs Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs-code?tabs=node-v3%2Cpython-v2%2Cisolated-process&pivots=programming-language-python

If anyone has successfully set up and run Azure Functions on a Mac M2, I would greatly appreciate some guidance.

Here are some details about my setup:

Mac M2 Pro machine running - Ventura 13.5.1
Azure Tools version - v1.2.0
Python Version - v3.11.5

I've already checked the official Azure documentation and forums, but firsthand experiences from the community would be invaluable.

Thanks in advance for your help!

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I recommend you open an issue on Github / Azure Functions repo. You will have a direct support from the team which builds it

Comment: looks like this error on an M1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75988713/microsoft-azure-webjobs-script-architecture-arm64-is-not-supported-for-language